# Require command not working on GEM Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have installed **Ruby**, **RailsInstaller** and **DevKit** on **C:/**.

The command

```
gem install pipedrive-ruby
```

works fine as below.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5Uoo.png)

When I test the instalation, it looks ok. Its shown on

```
gem list
```

but then when I try

```
require  'pipedrive-ruby'
```

Windows does not recognize.

I'm trying this gem https://github.com/GeneralScripting/pipedrive-ruby

Whats happening?

Comment: What is Windoes? Is it a command shell or Ruby REPL or something?

Comment: You may have more than one ruby version installed, and for some reason your gems are installing to a different ruby version than the one you're using in your terminal. The other possibility is that you're using bundler (i.e. the Gemfile) in your local directory which scopes the gems available in your environment to those that are explicitly specified in the Gemfile.

Comment: Are you using [Bundler](http://bundler.io/)?

Comment: @sawa It's Windows command line. Sorry It was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I can not start any Ruby code from cmd, it's pretty basic but for a noobie I didn't know. The require command must be inside a .rb file or if from command line it must be `"ruby -e "require 'pipedrive-ruby'"`

Living and learning.